# When assigning the result of an addition to a variable, calculator doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm experimenting with my very basic Javascript and I found a nice [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCF3GnTQJ4g&index=9&list=PL6n9fhu94yhUA99nOsJkKXBqokT3MBK0b) on how to make a very basic calculator in JS.

I tried following along with the video but I didn't want to just "copy-paste" what he was writing so I stopped and tried to do what I thought was the logic code...***WRONG*!**

**Here the problem**

*Why this doesn't work*?

```
function addNum() {
  let first = document.querySelector('.first').value;
  let second = document.querySelector('.second').value;
  let result = document.querySelector('.resultt').value;
  return result = first + second
}
```

I tried to assign the input related to the result to a variable but it doesn't work.

*But when I do this:* (as it was done in the tutorial)

```
function addNum() {
  let first = parseInt(document.querySelector('.first').value);
  let second = parseInt(document.querySelector('.second').value);
  document.querySelector('.resultt').value=first + second;
}
```

So without assigning the result to a variable, it works.

Why?

Comment: JavaScript uses *pass by value* semantics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value

Comment: @FelixKling - Just a nit-pick on terminology.  :-) *pass-by-value* and *pass-by-reference* have nothing to do with variable assignment. They're terms of art related to passing arguments into functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I would assume that the same behavior applies though (generally speaking, I know it does in JavaScript)? I.e. a language that uses pass-by-value will also do that for simple variable assignments. But maybe not...

Comment: @FelixKling - Understandable. :-) But they're really separate things. For instance, in C# `a = b` is always just copying a value from `b` to `a` (where "value" is either a primitive or an object reference), but if you pass `b` into a function, it can be by value (the default) or by reference (an `out` or `ref` parameter). But unless they've added it recently, C# still doesn't have a way to make `a = b` mean "make `a` a reference to `b` (like C++'s `&` IIRC -- but it's been years since I did any C++ :-) ).

Comment: (One of the things I like about C# vs. C++ is that `out` params require a keyword at the call site. `foo(a)` is always by value. To do something else, it has to be `foo(ref a)` or `foo(out a)`. In C++ `foo(a)` could be either depending on `foo`'s definition, which I found really hard to read. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
let result = document.querySelector('.resultt').value;
```

you're *copying* the value from the `value` property to the `result` variable. There's no ongoing link between them after that, they each just contain the same string. That means later, when you do `result = first + second`, all you're doing is updating `result`; that has no effect at all on `value`.

So you have to assign back to `value` as you do in your second code block.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that in this case, there shouldn't be a variable where the input doesn't recive nothing from the user, like the result input ?

Comment: @marcomarco - That's entirely a matter of style. It probably falls into the same category as whether a function should do `return a + b;` or `const result = a + b; return result;` Most people prefer the former, but the latter is often convenient for debugging (and they're treated the same by the compiler/JavaScript engine; in the case of JavaScript where source size matters, any decent minifier will handle minifying that).